# Borders around nodes in visual representation of graph

Tags: matlab, matlab-figure

I am trying to visualize a graph by using plot function in matlab. While the documentation is awesome, and there is a lot of useful key words, I run into a problem of visualizing a white node.

The colors of nodes are defined in other parts of my program, and I would want to avoid changing a color in that particular visualization. In particular, I thought that having borders around my nodes would be great, because you could see where is the white node.

I looked over the [documentation for plot function](https://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/matlab.graphics.chart.primitive.graphplot-properties.html#d117e493422) but I could not find any key word for borders around nodes. Maybe they are just called a different name.

```matlab
G = graph(edgs, 'lower', 'OmitSelfLoops');
plt = plot(G, 'EdgeColor',[0.9 0.9 0.9], EdgeAlpha',0.9);
plt.NodeColor = node_map((unique(sub_rows)+1), :);
```

where `edgs, node_map, sub_rows` are corresponding variables.

Is there any (hopefully simple) way of drawing borders around my nodes.
Thank you for your help!